# Login with textboxes in visual basic, 3 tries

Tags: vb.net, authentication, textbox

I'm making a login script in VB using textboxes.
My problem is that the msgbox which inform the user about attempts left keep looping itself as well and using up all the (3) tries.
Not sure what's wrong.

here is my code:

```
Dim cor_pw As String = "1234"
Dim cor_us As String = "abcd"
Dim tries1 As Integer = 3

tries1 -= 1

Do
    MsgBox("wrong combination, " & tries1 & " chances left to make it right.")

Loop Until textbox1.Text = cor_us And textbox2.Text = cor_pw Or tries1<= 0

If textbox1.Text = cor_us And textbox2.Text = cor_pw Then
    MsgBox("Congratulations! That's Correct!")
Else
    MsgBox("You've used all tries! " & tries1 & " chances left, good bye!")
    Me.Close()
End If
```

Comment: You need to decrement `tries1` inside your loop to have it count down and reach 0.

Comment: The code as is would never work as the user does not have an opportunity to re-enter the information. Get rid of the loop, have tries1 declared outside the scope of the login test which should be triggered by user hitting an OK button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an OK button that indicates the user has finished entering text.
In the event for the OK button you would

```
validate the text
If valid then you are good
otherwise increment the retry1 variable -- which must be declared at the Form (module) level!
now test retry1
if retry 1 is > 3 then display failure message and disable the OK button
otherwise display retry message 
exit the sub
```

At this point the user can reenter the values and then hit OK button again.
No loop.

Comment: my pleasure, it is often a good idea to try to draw these things out on a scrap of paper to get things straight before you start coding.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, wich I will keep in mind the next time I get stuck. Have a great day mate!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop event is in the wrong area(s)

```
Dim cor_pw As String = "1234"
Dim cor_us As String = "abcd"
Dim tries1 As Integer = 3

Do Until (textbox1.Text = cor_us And textbox2.Text = cor_pw) Or tries1<= 0
    If textbox1.Text = cor_us And textbox2.Text = cor_pw Then
        MsgBox("Congratulations! That's Correct!")
    Else
        MsgBox("You've used all tries! " & tries1 & " chances left, good bye!")
        Me.Close()
    End If
    MsgBox("wrong combination, " & tries1 & " chances left to make it right.")
    tries1 -= 1
Loop
```

Comment: That one launched all the error-messages in a row til the program shut down aswell :\

Comment: This looks like homework. You should probably focus more on explaining how loops work rather than just giving him/her an easy A. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812)

Comment: @Freshman, the idea is sound, you just have to put things in the correct locations.  Though this is a homework question, you put in a good faith effort.  Look at PatFromCanada's post above for some psuedocode to get you rolling.  My code is by no means complete, and was just a nudge.